# Upload subproject artifacts to Bintray using gradle and bintray plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, multi-project, artifact, bintray

I have a root project and some subprojects and all of them produce artifacts.
I configured bintray in the top build script (gradle) in a similar way to what I did for artifactory (same publication/configuration).
When it comes to upload artifacts to artifactory using "artifactoryPublish", all artifacts (from root and subprojects) are correctly uploaded.
When running "bintrayUpload" however, only artifacts from the root project are uploaded and I receive this kind of error for subprojects:

```
> Task :sub1:bintrayUpload
Putting task artifact state for task ':sub1:bintrayUpload' into context took 0.0 secs.

Executing task ':sub1:bintrayUpload' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Gradle Bintray Plugin version: 1.8.0
Skipping task 'sub1:bintrayUpload' because user or apiKey is null.
```

It looks like the configuration defined in root project has not been passed through to subprojects. How can I make this happen?
Some subproject code is autogenerated and hence, I do not want to modify subproject build scripts and would like all the logic in top script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify bintray credentials.
Provide details like this below in your project.

> build.gradle(libary module)

```
ext {
   bintrayRepo = "Awesome Library"
   bintrayName = "com.example.awesome-library"
   libraryName = "awesome-library"

   publishedGroupId = 'com.example.awesome-library'
   artifact = 'awesome_library'
   libraryVersion = '1.0'

   libraryDescription = "Description...."
   siteUrl = 'https://www.example.com/'
   gitUrl = 'https://github.com/me/awesome-library.git'
   developerId = '....'
   developerName = '....'
   developerEmail = '.....'
   licenseName = 'The Apache Software LIcense, Version 2.0'
   licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
   allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
```

> local.properties

```
bintray.user=username
bintray.apikey=*****************
```